# iAD banner view rotated to landscape but the ad when loaded still has the portrait size

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa, iad

In this app only one scene is allowed to change its orientation and because of that its contents are rotated programmatically. The adBannerView is one of the subviews and it rotates and resizes correctly when in landscape, however, the size of an ad when loaded does not follow - it is still displayed with portrait dimensions.

I create the Ad Banner View using this:

```
    CGRect bannerRect = UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation) ? CGRectMake(0, 20 + yOffset, 480, 32) : CGRectMake(0, 20 + yOffset, 320, 50);

_adBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:bannerRect];
[_adBannerView setDelegate:self];
[_adBannerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[self.view addSubview:_adBannerView];
```

And then I rotate it using this:

```
    [_adBannerView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)];
```

The picture below shows the bottom of the view. Blue is the background colour of the adBannerView where the ad should be.

[image: Bottom of the view.]

Also, when I check the ADBannerView frame size in landscape I get this NSRect: {{268, -248}, {32, 568}}.

Comment: It was wrong to set the transform on the adBannerView, once its parent's frame was set correctly, it started working.